# Ckeditor5 - List 'type' attribute on ul / ol tags?

Tags: javascript, list, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm looking to allow the attribute of '`type`' on `<ul> and <ol>` tags generated by `ckEditor 5.`

When setting data via the `setData()` and passing an `<ol>` with `type="A"` the `CkEditor` list plugin strips any attribute tags from the list.

Code:

```
window.CKEditor.setData("<ol type=\"A\"><li>hello</li><li>hello</li><li>hello</li></ol>");
```

Output:

```
<ol>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>hello</li>
</ol>
```

I have been trying to modify the `ckEditor` list plugin files but so far have only managed to get the attribute on the `<li>` items by registering `'type'` as an allowed attribute and setting an attribute to attribute conversion within `listediting.js`

Code:

```
editor.model.schema.register( 'listItem', {
            inheritAllFrom: '$block',
            allowAttributes: [ 'listType', 'listIndent', 'type' ]
        } );

editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute( { model: 'type', view: 'type' },  );
```

OUTPUT:

```
<ol>
    <li type="A">hello</li>
    <li type="A">hello</li>
    <li type="A">hello</li>
</ol>
```

How would I allow the type attribute on the generated `<ul> and <ol>` html tags?

Do I need to register them as schemas with allowed attributes or set a conversion ?

This has been raised a number of times on `github` as an issue.  https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1032

Does anyone know if a solution exists already or can advise on how to proceed?